# cookie is not being set on browser in CROS nodejs?

Tags: node.js, express, cookies, cross-domain, setcookie

Im using nodejs as backend and sending the cookie from server side . here is my code

```
response.cookie('access_token', token, 
{ maxAge: 900000, httpOnly: true ,secure: true, domain: temp_hostname});
```

this code successfully set the cookie on client side but when i use this code for cross domain . server is sending the cookie on client side but it is no being set on browser. i need help in setting cookie in  cross domain  .sorry for my bad english . thanks in advance